# Насколько хорошо индексируются на Angular.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, поиск, seo

По сути роуты правильные... У каждой статьи есть своя ссылка, но эта ссылка после #. + данные появляются после загрузки страницы...

Не могу найти статьи по этой теме... все очень старые (2013-2014 год)

Походу должно индексироваться, но не уверен. Интересуют извесные поисковики (Google Yandex)

Comment: пока js переваривает только гугл, яндекс в процессе (движуха точно была), рано или поздно всеравно все за гуглом ес-сно подтянутся

Answer (score 1):

Точно могу сказать, что гугл индексирует. На одном из сайтов у меня рекламный баннер подгружался через некоторое время(3-5сек.) после загрузки всей страницы. Подгружался дополнительным запросом. Так вот в статистике переходов по этому баннеру я часто встречал гуглобота. Поискового бота от яндекса пока не встречал.